# How to sort 2 list in the exact same order in python

Tags: python

I have a leader board, and two lists, one for names and one for scores. The leader board prints out the names and scores perfectly fine, but it is unsorted. I was wondering if there was any way to sort the score list, and then sort the names in the exact same way as the score, as to keep them linked. This is my code so far:

```
def showLeaderboard():
    print("Here is the leaderboard")
    leadFile = open("leaderboard.txt","r")
    leads = []
    names = []
    scores = []
    lead = leadFile.readline()

    while lead != "":
        leads.append(lead)
        lead = leadFile.readline()

    leadFile.close()

    for lead in leads:
        fields = lead.split(",")
        names.append(fields[0])
        scores.append(fields[1])

    for i in range(len(names)):
        print(f"Name: {names[i]}, Score: {scores[i]}")
```

leaderboard.txt:

```
mr epic man,3,
i am bad,1,
i am half decent at this,3,
mid,3,
```

Comment: add pls example of leaderboard.txt

Comment: Why don't you make a list of (name, score) tuples and sort that based on score. Then you can split it into two lists.

Comment: As said by Mark Meyer, it's best to make a combnation of (name, score) in tuple and sort with `sorted(list_tuples_name_score, key=lambda x: x[1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def showLeaderboard():
    print("Here is the leaderboard")
    leads = []
    scores_names=[]

    with open("leaderboard.txt","r") as file:
        leads = file.read().split('\n')[:-1]

    for lead in leads:
        fields = lead.split(",")
        name = fields[0]
        score = fields[1]
        scores_names.append([name, score])
    scores_names=sorted(scores_names, key=lambda x: x[0])

    for i in range(len(scores_names)):
        print(f"Name: {scores_names[i][0]}, Score: {scores_names[i][1]}")
```